# contents of activate template in django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

According to the official [docs](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html)  ,the `registration/activate.html` is

> Used if account activation fails. With the default setup, has the context :activation_key

So,what should I put in this template?An error message?Or, an activation link like

```
http://{{ site.domain }}{% url registration_activate activation_key %}
```

Currently I am putting this link in the `activation_email.txt`

Please tell me which is the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is only shown in case of error. In case of success, it will redirect to a success url. So, you should put an error message in this template